# NPE when not injecting mock data for mapper class (spring boot)

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am using spring boot. I have the below mapper class to map the entity object to model object.

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface PersonMapper {
    PersonEntity personModelToPersonEntity(PersonModel pm)
    PersonModel personEntityToPersonModel(PersonEntity pe)
}
```

Service class:

```java
@Service
public class MyService{

    @Autowired
    PersonMapper personMapper;
    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepo;

    @Transactional
    public List<Person> getDetails() {
        List<Person> personList = personRepo.findAll();
        List<PersonModel> pm = personMapper.personEntityToPersonModel(personList);
    ...
    ...
    }
}
```

I have the below Junit test case, where I'm mocking the data.

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class PersonTest{
        
    @InjectMocks
    PersonService personService;
    // @Mock
    // PersonMapper personMapper;
        
    @Mock
    PersonRepository personRepo;
        
    @Test
    void getPersonDetailsTest() {
        given(personRepo.findAll()).willReturn(mymockData);
   
    //given(personMapper.personEntityToPersonModel(..).willReturn(..);
        ...
    }
}
```

Eveything works if I mock the personMapper, but i don't want to mock the mapper class, when test case is executing, as i'm sending the mock entity data using "`given(personRepo.findAll()).willReturn(mymockData);`" so when it hits the service it should automatically convert the mock data sent to model object. In my case when i have commented the code for mocking mapper class, it is throwing `NullPointerException` in service class at the mapper object.

Comment: Because nothing is there. You need to mock it, or inject it manually.

Answer (score 0):

As @M. Denium said, nothing is there, because application context isn't raising with `MockitoExtension`. So, you can either mock your `PersonMapper` and stub its behavior or inject it manually with `ReflectionTestUtils`:

```
 @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
 public class PersonTest{

    @InjectMocks
    PersonService personService;

    PersonMapper personMapper = Mappers.getMapper(PersonMapper.class);

    @Mock
    PersonRepository personRepo;


    @Test
    void getPersonDetailsTest() {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(personService, "personMapper", personMapper);

        given(personRepo.findAll()).willReturn(mymockData);

        ...
    }
}
```